# using jQuery to uncheck all checkboxes and then check the clicked one

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
      <div class="pricing-levels-2">
        <p>Which level would you like? (Click all that apply)</p>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 4<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 5<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 6<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 7<br>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-levels-3">
        <p>Which level would you like? (Click all that apply)</p>
        <input class="single-checkbox"type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 1<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 2<br>
        <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Level 3<br>
      </div>
```

I want the `.pricing-levels-2` checkboxes to clear each time I click in one of them, so I did:

```
jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').on('click', function(){
  jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').attr('checked', false);
  jQuery(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

But the problem is that now ALL the checkboxes clear, even the one I'm selecting. So I can't select any (I want the one I'm clicking to be selected).

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').on('click', function(){
  jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  jQuery(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

by [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
   jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').on('click', function(){
      jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
      jQuery(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    });
```

reference [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

by [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').on('click', function(){
  jQuery('.pricing-levels-2 .single-checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  jQuery(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```